# Why there are many i686 RPMs in CentOS x86_64 repository?

Tags: linux, centos, package, rpm

I'm looking at [http://mirror.centos.org/centos-7/7.3.1611/os/x86_64/Packages](http://mirror.centos.org/centos-7/7.3.1611/os/x86_64/Packages/) where there are many i686 RPMs included.

Not every x86_64 RPM has its i686 RPM counterpart though.

I thought i686 packages are for 32 bit machine only, but why are they present under x86_64 directory? Are they really needed for 64 bit distribution?

Comment: Wrong place to post this - it's unrelated to programming q&a, and off-topic for StackOverflow. Perhaps post your query to the unix stackexchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought i686 packages are for 32 bit machine only, but why are they
>   present under x86_64 directory? Are they really needed for 64 bit
>   distribution?

These 32-bit libraries are provided for the purpose of backward compatibility.

Comment: Thanks. But in what way? Do you mean if I wanted to run a 32bit binary on the 64 bit machine, I can install the i686 package to make it happen?

Comment: @JackYang - Not all, but whichever package is available in i686 rpm, the corresponding **32-bit compatible applications** would work normally under the 64-bit OS. Mind that it is not applicable for all other applications which are running as 64-bit executable but have dependencies on 3rd party 32-bit plugins (you should always perform testing for confirmation). In those cases, you should either use 32-bit application with plugin OR don't use the plugin.